# How can I set my default shell to start up tmux

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, tmux, bashrc

I would like my default bash shell to go straight into tmux instead of my always having to type tmux every time.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

[Start tmux on every shell login](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Tmux#Start_tmux_on_every_shell_login), from Arch wiki, seems to work. Simply add the following line of bash code to your `.bashrc` before your aliases; the code for other shells is very similar:

```
[[ $TERM != "screen" ]] && exec tmux
```

Comment: For me this also required `[[ $- != *i* ]] && return` to not being an infinite loop (from the same page)

Comment: This is a bad solution since the `TERM` might be set to some other value by the user's `.tmux.conf` file. Better to check whether the `TMUX` variable is set or not.

Comment: Can confirm this works for zsh as well.

Answer (score 235):

[@StarNamer's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/43604/377345) is generally accurate, though I typically include the following tests to make sure that

1. `tmux` exists on the system
2. we're in an interactive shell, and
3. `tmux` doesn't try to run within itself

So, I would add this to the `.bashrc`:

```
if command -v tmux &> /dev/null && [ -n "$PS1" ] && [[ ! "$TERM" =~ screen ]] && [[ ! "$TERM" =~ tmux ]] && [ -z "$TMUX" ]; then
  exec tmux
fi
```

---

References

- Using bash's `command` to check for existence of a command - http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html#SHELL_BUILTIN_COMMANDS
- Why to use `command` instead of `which` to check for the existence of commands - https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/85250
- Using `$PS1` to check for interactive shell - https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Is-this-Shell-Interactive_003f.html
- Expected state of `$TERM` environment variable "for all programs running inside tmux" - http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tmux.1.html#WINDOWS_AND_PANES

Comment: Nice, I have needed `command` before but didn't realize it existed.

Comment: I use Linux Mint, which lets you map certain hotkeys to commands, and (un-kosher as it may be to some..) I've got bash shells with commands starting up there, e.g. `Win`+`Alt`+`B` edits my `.bashrc`. Vim can't open for some reason if the above is at the top of the bashrc. I've wrapped the middle line in another if statement, `if [ ! -z "$PS1" ]; then`...`fi` (checking that it's running in interactive mode)

Comment: this `exec` statement doesn't let you exit tmux without quitting the entire terminal! :|

Comment: @LouisMaddox: `exec` replaces the current process with a new one - in this case, it replaces the bash login shell with tmux, so when tmux exits then there is no other terminal to fall back to :)

Comment: For those curious, it looks like `command -v` tests for the existence of tmux in the path.

Comment: Am i missing something or would this not attach to an existing tmux session?

Comment: @rjt That's correct, this starts a new session by design. If you prefer to attach to an existing tmux session simply replace `exec tmux` with your preferred flavor of `tmux attach`

Comment: @user7089 but this will crash if there is no existing tmux session (e.g. after a reboot) right?

Comment: instead of `exec tmux` I use `exec tmux new-session -A -s main` so I will always have a session called main and attach to it (instead of creating a new one everytime I connect to my remote machine) but it will not crash like using `tmux attach` in case there is no session available (found here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/176885/256942)

Comment: @VerenaHaunschmid Nice find. That's a great approach for those who want to re-attach to their existing session

Comment: I think this is a great approach. But, *sometimes* I want to start a bare shell without tmux. Given the suggested setup, what would be the simplest way to do that?

Comment: @KlasMellbourn wrap the `exec tmux` command inside an if statement like: `read -p "Run tmux? (y/n)" -n 1 -r` `echo` `if [[ $REPLY =~ ^[Yy]$ ]]; then` `exec tmux` `fi` `fi`

Comment: @VerenaHaunschmid This loads the vscode/codium terminal in tmux when running the terminal. And I cannot get out of that without leaving the loaded environment that vscode/codium uses. Since I often use codium, I cannot make any tmux default session at start, since anything I do with that session happens in the terminal of vscode/codium as well.

Comment: I'm using vscode just like questionto42 and noticed that when I quit vscode, the session is (as expected) detached... but when I open it back again, it creates a new one. This considered, it seems huangzonghao's answer would be a better solution.

Comment: This broke my VSCode (which for some reason uses an interactive terminal during startup?) but adding a like `"$TERM" =~ dumb` fixed the issue.

Comment: i had the same issue, that within vscode a terminal with the tmux session was opened, the same session i used already in my normal terminal, which was not nice, for mitigating this you can see my answer, its basically this answer + vscode without tmux, just scroll down a bit

Answer (score 44):

Adding a line like

```
[ -z "$TMUX"  ] && { tmux attach || exec tmux new-session && exit;}
```

in your bashrc file will probably do the job. Note this line will exit ssh and terminate the connection once you detach or exit tmux. I like this configuration as it saves key strokes to terminate the connection. But if you don't love this(which I think is very unlikely) and would rather remain in the login shell after termination, just remove the `exit` part:

```
[ -z "$TMUX"  ] && { tmux attach || exec tmux new-session;}
```

Also note you shouldn't wrap `tmux attach` with `exec`, as this would cause the connection to be closed when there are no tmux sessions to attach to.

Comment: I've added this line to my .bashrc, but now when I start a terminal, I get some messages: /home/z/.tmux.conf:10: no current session
(the message repeats for lines 11, 13, 14, 15). Those lines are things like "set default-command "exec bash"" and "set default-terminal "screen-256color".

Comment: @MattG Feel like it's something wrong with the tmux configuration file.

Comment: I was unable to login with this setting. Running Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: @Richard what's the error message?

Comment: After logging in, something would fail and take be back to the login screen. See my answer for a fix.

Comment: What is the role of the `{}` in this command?

Comment: this solution is perfect for using with vscode. When I close vscode the session is detached and stays running. When I open vscode again, it attaches back and I resume from where I left off! Thank you!

Comment: I would suggest adding `[[ -t 0 ]] &&` at the start of that line, because if this is configured on a server and you try to add an ssh key (ssh-copy-id) or copy a file through scp, it will fail with `error opening terminal: not a terminal`. This solves the error. The complete line would be: `[[ -t 0 ]] && [ -z "$TMUX"  ] && { tmux attach || exec tmux new-session;}`

Answer (score 8):

There is command `chsh` which changes login shell. Consult `man chsh`.

Make `tmux` your login shell, but don't forget to configure the `default-shell` setting for `tmux` first!

Example of `~/.tmux.conf`:

```
set-option -g default-shell "/bin/bash"
```

You need to test this first, before setting `tmux` as your login shell.

Comment: `tmux` is not a shell, it's a [terminal multiplexer](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/) like GNU screen.  Interestingly, it does support the `-c` option according to the [man page](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=tmux&sektion=1), so it may work like a shell just enough to use it as your login shell, but I suspect it won't work properly in all situations, e.g. graphical logins via gdm/kdm.

Comment: Although this is sensible and backed by the documentation, it seems to break direct command execution via SSH (something like `ssh $some_server echo foo`).

Comment: tmux as of at least 1.8 on Ubuntu adds itself to `/etc/shells`, so it is a valid login shell.

Comment: This requires you configure the `default-shell` setting in the tmux configuration to point to an actual shell.

Answer (score 8):

I'm successfully using

```
case $- in *i*)
    [ -z "$TMUX" ] && exec tmux
esac
```

in my `.zshrc`. If you're using bash, put it in your `.bashrc` instead.

---

I also just tried setting `tmux` as my default shell (`chsh -s $(which tmux)`) and it seems to break direct command execution via SSH, e.g. `ssh $some_server echo foo` will not produce any output.

Comment: Why are you using `case $- in *i*)`?

Comment: @AhmadIsmail `$-` contains the current shell options, including `i` if the shell is interactive (i.e. a user prompt is requested, rather than directly executing a command). `case … in *i*)` is a fairly portable way to check if a variable contains the letter `i` anywhere (no need to break out `expr` or `[[` and regular expressions for something so simple).

Comment: And for the last part, `$TMUX` is set inside tmux sessions, so we can check if it's unset/empty to only spawn tmux if we are not already inside a tmux session.

Answer (score 8):

I combined the extensive checks, with the conditional session checking, and put my own spin on it, to create a default session that is connected to or else created. Unless you are inside of another tmux session, or other protective conditions are met.

```
if command -v tmux &> /dev/null && [ -n "$PS1" ] && [[ ! "$TERM" =~ screen ]] && [[ ! "$TERM" =~ tmux ]] && [ -z "$TMUX" ]; then
  tmux a -t default || exec tmux new -s default && exit;
fi
```

Based on these answers:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/306165/198110

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/113768/198110

Answer (score 7):

Go to terminal preferances.
[image]

And then click to "command" bar.
[image]

Check the "Run a custom command instead of my sell" and write whatever command you want to execute at the startup of your terminal.

Comment: I tried this before getting here. However, I can't use the `tmux a || tmux new-session` command. When there's a session to connect, it connects, but, otherwise, the terminal closes immediately. This forced me to use another TTY to revert the configuration (which may be scary for newby users).

Answer (score 3):

Adding to @Louis Maddox 's answer, I would execute tmux part with;

```
(exec tmux attach || exec tmux new-session)
```

Comment: I use `exec sh -c 'tmux a || tmux'`, which (after looking at your answer) will probably make bad things happen if tmux can't start for any reason.....  thanks, I'll use yours from now on :)

Comment: `tmux new -A -s mysession` will probably work too.

Answer (score 3):

This is in my `~/.profile` (I'm using `ksh93`):

```
if [[ -z "$TMUX" ]]; then
    if tmux has-session 2>/dev/null; then
        exec tmux attach
    else
        exec tmux
    fi
fi
```

If the `TMUX` environment variable is unset/empty, then we're not already in a tmux session, so...

If `tmux has-session` returns with a zero exit status (true), there is an available session to attach to. Attach to it.

If not, create a new session.

It's also possible to use `tmux` as your login shell. If you do this, however, make sure to set `default-shell` to an actual shell in your `~/.tmux.conf` file (see the tmux manual for more info about this).

Answer (score 2):

None of the above responses worked for me - `exec tmux` prevents me closing tmux without quitting the shell (whether it's opened with `Ctrl` + `T` or from the application menu).

I use Linux Mint, which lets you map certain hotkeys to commands, and (un-kosher as it may be to some..) I've got bash shells with commands starting up there, e.g. `Win`+`Alt`+`B` does some sort of convoluted `bash -exec(vim)` statement to edit my .bashrc, so it acts like a regular shell.

tmux loaded rather than vim under that situation after placing the above at the top of my `.bashrc`. I've wrapped the tmux executing line in another if statement, checking that it's running in interactive mode.

```
if command -v tmux>/dev/null; then
        if [ ! -z "$PS1" ]; then # unless shell not loaded interactively, run tmux
                [[ ! $TERM =~ screen ]] && [ -z $TMUX ] && tmux
        fi
fi
```

You could wrap all that onto one line but for readability I think that's fine.

Comment: Adding a ampersand would solved that issue like so. `[[ ! $TERM =~ screen ]] && [ -z $TMUX ] && exec tmux &`

Answer (score 2):

You could (and as of now probably should) use `sudo chsh $(logname)` command to set `/usr/bin/tmux`, or whatever is the path to it, as a default shell, then add the following to `~/.tmux.conf`:

```
set-option -g default-shell </path/to/your/favourite/shell>
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but tmux ain't a shell, is a shell/screen multiplexer. What OP meant by "shell" is launching tmux by default, with the default shell in each pane. Point is, you can't set default-shell to tmux afaik because it ain't a shell and if you could anyway, it could result in tmux complaining about "tmux session inside a tmux session" if you would open a new pane inside tmux which would use the default shell.

Comment: @Eksapsy You are wrong. I have had my default shell set to `/usr/bin/tmux` for the last 5 years and that's how _it is_ supposed to work, it doesn't complain about anything. After it fires up it starts another tmux session (see the second paragraph of https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tmux.1.html), and using the option mentioned above, it fires up ZSH in that session's window. You can have any binary whatsoever as your a login shell. `tmux` does handle being login shell without an issue, even when logging in via SSH.

Comment: @Eksapsy FTR, here's what `man tmux` says about `tmux -c`:
                   Execute shell-command using the default shell. If necessary, the tmux server will be started to retrieve the default-shell option. This option is
                  for compatibility with sh(1) **when tmux is used as a
                   login shell**.

Comment: Im sorry but to me your instructions didn't work either. `tmux` doesn't exist as a shell in `/etc/shells`. I added it manually, even if you're not supposed to do that, and `chsh` to `tmux` anyway. Didn't work again. Then added `set-option -g default-shell /usr/bin/zsh`. Didn't work either. The most important thing here though is, that `tmux` didn't appear as a shell in `/etc/shells` at all. Maybe I'm doing something wrong, but it only shows that this is not the default best way to do things? Usually when you install a shell it sets itself inside `/etc/shells` on its own.

Comment: @Eksapsy what exactly didn't work? What have you gotten instead? Where have you added the `default-shell` command? It's supposed to be in your `~/.tmux.conf`

Comment: @Eksapsy from `man chsh`: The only restriction placed on the login shell is that the command name must be listed in
/etc/shells, **unless the invoker is the superuser, and then any value may be added.**

Comment: @Eksapsy This is what my postinstall script for Ubuntu does and it's never been an issue - albeit via `usermod`, but the end result is exactly the same, i.e. the right line in `/etc/passwd` has `/usr/bin/tmux` in the login shell field: https://github.com/MrMino/dotfiles/blob/postinstall/postinstall.sh#L87

Comment: Firstly, you're very helpful, thanks! The tmux command was in `~/.tmux.conf`, seems like the issue is completely something else. `chsh` doesn't work in general, not just with `tmux`. I mean, it changes `/etc/passwd` but it doesn't change `$SHELL`. I tried setting the gnome-terminal's command preference to "Run command as a login shell" but that didn't work either. In any case, you've been helpful with your guidance, but this seems like a different issue and it's an issue with my system. So probably continuing this here would be against comment etiquete :P Thanks, learned a new thing or two.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123711/discussion-between-eksapsy-and-blazej-michalik).

Answer (score 1):

I use the following for zsh.

```
if command -v tmux &> /dev/null && [[ -z "$TMUX" ]]
then
    tmux new-session -c $PWD
fi
```

The difference with existing solutions being, If you are using a DE and try to use 'Right Click > Open In Terminal' then it will open in current location.

Another difference is, we do not use `exec` in this particular case. Please read Mark Hansen's Blog titled [An Argument for Auto-Starting Tmux](https://www.markhansen.co.nz/auto-start-tmux/).

> Some people suggest you exec tmux, this replaces your entire shell's
> process with tmux, and can fail pretty badly if tmux has errors. At
> least running tmux directly will fall back to your terminal if tmux
> has an error. It also makes it easy to drop the tmux session if you
> don't want it - just detach. The extra process is a small cost to pay.

For Fish shell, I follow similar steps. I put the following in the `conf.d`:

```
if status is-interactive
    if not set -q TMUX
        tmux new-session -c $PWD
    end
end
```

There is also the Tiny Frames problem.

> tmux will auto-size its window frame to the size of the smallest
> terminal attached to the session. Often this results in a tiny laptop
> terminal window making the usable space on a huge desktop screen tiny.

Even in my machine, connecting to same session via two terminals does not end up well. Same command mirror in both terminals.

[image: Terminal Mirroring]

The point is using code like bellow does not work for me.

```
if tmux has-session 2>/dev/null; then
    tmux attach
else
    exec tmux
fi
```

So I have a **fish script** which does the following:

- if no session then create new session
- if has unattached session then give option to connect to one of them (after attaching, cd to $PWD)
- if do not want to attach to unattached session, then create new session

Here is the script (I put it in `conf.d`):

```
if status is-interactive
    if not set -q TMUX
        if tmux list-sessions &>/dev/null
            set -l array_unattached

            for i in (tmux list-sessions -F "#{session_attached} #{session_name} \"#{session_path}\"")
                if test (echo $i | cut -d' ' -f1) -eq 0
                    set -a  array_unattached (echo $i | cut --complement -d ' ' -f 1)
                end
            end

            if set -q array_unattached[1]
                set -l selection (printf '%s\n' $array_unattached | rofi -dmenu -p "Select tmux session")
                if test $status -eq 0
                    set -l session_name (echo $selection | cut -d ' ' -f 1)
                    tmux send-keys -t $session_name:1.1 "^C"
                    tmux send-keys -t $session_name:1.1 "cd $PWD &> /dev/null" ENTER
                    tmux attach-session -t $session_name:1.1
                else
                    tmux new-session -c $PWD
                end
            end
        else
            tmux new-session -c $PWD
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the below line to `~/.config/fish/conf.d/omf.fish`

```
if not set -q TMUX
    set -g TMUX tmux new-session -d -s base
    eval $TMUX
    tmux attach-session -d -t base
end
```

The above worked on Fedora 34. However, on exit, only tmux is exited and the running session remains active.

Answer (score 1):

There seem to be two classes of answers here:

1. Those that just "start tmux" (`exec tmux`) using various techniques and (preferably) wrappers for error handling.  E.g. `exec tmux`
2. Those that first attempt to attach to an existing tmux and then fallback to the first method if an existing session doesn't exist.  E.g. `tmux attach || exec tmux`.

This second method can be simplified and made more efficient with:

```
exec tmux new -A
```

The `-A` flag to `new` (short for `new-session`):

- Checks to see if an existing tmux session exists
- Attaches to it if if so
- Starts a new session if not

In addition to being more concise than the longer form, it's also theoretically slightly more efficient, since tmux only has to start once, rather than potentially twice (once to check, again to actually run if it wasn't running).

I use a slightly longer form personally:

```
exec tmux new -AD -t main -s main
```

This:

- Makes sure that there is only one session-group and session running (named `main`)
- Detaches any other running tmux client.

I do still recommend wrapping this in an `if` statement per [user7089's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/113768/432493).

Answer (score 1):

Not quite what the original question asked, but a flexible alternative is to add

```
history -s "tmux attach"
```

to your `~/.profile`.  That way when logging in you can just use the up arrow and enter to start tmux back up.

Answer (score 0):

this make tmux open by default on all new shell of user

```
cmd='[ $TERM == screen ] || exec tmux'
echo -e "$cmd\n$(cat ~/.bashrc)" > ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: This is little more than a rewrite of the accepted answer, from eight years ago —  better answers have been posted since then.

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue where I could not login (on Ubuntu 20.04). I added the following tweak to huangzonghao's answer:

```
# autoload tmux - place at EOF (end-of-file) within ~/.bashrc
# if shell is interactive, and TMUX var is set...
[[ $- == *i* ]] && [[ -z "${TMUX}" ]] && { tmux attach || exec tmux new-session && exit; }
```

Answer (score 0):

if tmux already installed on your system , do this:
`sudo usermod -s $(which tmux) USERNAME`
now your user configured for use tmux as default shell .

now config tmux as your preferred shell :
`set-option -g default-shell "/bin/bash"`
or any other configuration you want ....
Note: tmux execute /bin/bash , so `/etc/bashrc` or `$USER/.bashrc` loaded immediately .

Comment: This seems to have already been mentioned: [How can I set my default shell to start up tmux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/333760)

Answer (score 0):

If someone wants to start tmux session always **BUT NOT** within Visual Studio Code, i did the following.

Its basically the same like [@user7089](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/7089/user7089) [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/113768/394094), so for explanation look at his answer, i just added the exclude vscode part

do this in your vscode settings.json

```
{
...
    "terminal.integrated.profiles.linux": {
        "bash": {
            "path": "bash",
            "icon": "terminal-bash"
        },
    ...
    },
    "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.linux": "bash",
    "terminal.integrated.env.linux": {
        "LAUNCHED": "vscode"
    },    
}
```

do this in your ~/.bashrc

```
if command -v tmux &> /dev/null && [ -n "$PS1" ] &&  [[ ! "$LAUNCHED" == "vscode" ]] && [[ ! "$TERM" =~ screen ]] && [[ ! "$TERM" =~ tmux ]] && [ -z "$TMUX" ]; then
  exec tmux new-session -A -s main
fi
```

Answer (score -1):

Add this into your `~/.tmux.conf`

```
set -g default-command /usr/local/bin/fish
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question mate! ;)

Answer (score -3):

As Mikel already stated in his comment to have tmux as your login shell can have side effects. But you can make `tmux` your default shell, literally. A user's default shell is defined in /etc/passwd. So you can become root and edit /etc/passwd, e.g. `sudo vi /etc/passwd` search for the line that begins with your username. It probably ends with `:/bin/bash`. Change /bin/bash to /usr/bin/tmux and now tmux is your default login shell.

However, no guarantee that this won't cause problems!

What may work better is to *NOT* do anything that requries root privileges. I would try to create a file in my home directoy named .bash_login and start tmux from within that file: `echo "tmux" >~/.bash_login.

This should work, but you have to try and find our yourself, b/c the bash documentation is not very exact about what file is read and executed when.

Comment: What your first paragraph describes is what `chsh` does! Except that your way requires being root and is error-prone. Running `tmux` from `.bash_login` is *more* likely to break remote logins.