# How to start tmux with attach if a session exists

Tags: tmux

If I use

```
tmux attach
```

I can attach to a running session but if there is no session running, I only get the error

```
no sessions
```

How can I automatically start a new session if there is none running? something like

```
tmux attach-or-create-new-session
```

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3432536/how-to-create-new-tmux-session-if-none-exists

Answer (score 80, accepted):

The answer is much simpler. Just put this in your `~/.tmux.conf` file:

```
# if run as "tmux attach", create a session if one does not already exist
new-session -n $HOST
```

If you run `tmux attach` and there is a session, then it will attach to that session (whether it's already attached or not). If there is *not* a session already then it will create one for you.

Comment: this is a neat trick, but there is a caveat: if `tmux` is invoked without arguments, it will create a new session and then create a second session as soon it reaches this line in your `~/.tmux.conf`. You can see this issue by executing `tmux ls` after creating the **first** session. In practice, after you put this in your file, you cannot call `tmux` with no arguments anymore

Comment: So you would have to add an alias `alias tmux="tmux attach"` to prevent this problem

Comment: @BrunoPolaco: what is the big caveat with an extra empty tmux session running all the time (apart from that it doesn't look tidy in the task-list)?

Comment: @rubo77 Resources. Some people have a few default tools, windows, panes, etc created when they launch `tmux`.

Answer (score 302):

If naming your session is okay, then it's easy to do with the `new-session` command:

```bsh
tmux new-session -A -s main
```

where `main` is the session name that will be attached to or created if needed.

From `man tmux`:

> The **`-A`** flag makes **`new-session`** behave like **`attach-session`** if *session-name* already exists;
> in this case, **`-D`** behaves like **`-d`** to **`attach-session`**.

This can be shortened to rely on the default session name (which is `0`):

```bsh
tmux new -As0
```

Please also note that the `-A` option was introduced in [tmux version `1.8` on 26 March 2013](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/blob/1.8/CHANGES#L44). For earlier versions, use:

```bsh
tmux attach || tmux
```

Comment: In my alias list: `alias "tmux-attach-or-create-main-session=tmux new-session -A -s main"`. Thanks for the tip! Manual page: http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man1/tmux.1

Comment: `tmux: unknown option -- A` This only seems to be available in recent versions.

Comment: This is the method I used, but you can no longer use "tmux detach".  You need to use the shortcut <ctrl>b - d to save and exit an existing session.

Comment: `[ -z "$TMUX" ] && exec tmux new -As .` this is what I use in my `.bashrc`.

Comment: +1 for pointing to an intrinsic feature which eliminates the need for shell-specific scripting.

Comment: As screen-transitioner, this command is way too long compared to `screen -xR main`. It can be shortened to `tmux new -As main`, which is acceptable with only 2 extra characters.

Comment: If you usually only work with one session, it's default name is `0`, so you can do: `tmux new-session -A -s 0`.

Comment: Nice! I came up with `tmux a || tmux` which works for me.

Answer (score 52):

This will start a new session if attach gives an error:

```
tmux attach || tmux new
```

So an alias will do the job:

```
tm="tmux attach || tmux new"
```

Comment: You can even make it shorter by changing `tmux attach` for `tmux a`

Comment: While this is functional, Wesley Baugh's solution uses tmux's built-in functionality to do the same thing

Comment: fwiw this does seem like the best answer for older versions, before -A was introduced (e.g. v1.6)

Comment: Do you need the "new"?

Comment: `tmux a || tmux`

Answer (score 9):

To expand on Wesley Baugh's answer (which was double-nesting sessions for me when used in .bashrc on logins) and add a bit of flexibility since I often use `sudo -s` on servers (which would dutifully load my .bashrc again and double nest), here's what I have in my .bashrc:

```
if [ -z "$TMUX" ] && [ ${UID} != 0 ]
then
    tmux new-session -A -s main
fi
```

This checks for a tmux session and makes sure you aren't superuser before creating a new session or attaching to that existing one named `main`.

Answer (score 5):

If you're using this inside a .shrc file or similar with `exec` I'd recommend

```
if tmux ls &> /dev/null; then
  exec tmux attach
else
  exec tmux
fi
```

Comment: For a more in depth example see https://github.com/aaronjameslang/dotfiles/blob/master/.zshrc

Comment: Isn't the equivalent of just `tmux && exec tmux attach || exec tmux`?

Comment: It's worth to mention that it may block from creating new windows in the result (i.e. `Prefix + c`).

Answer (score 4):

Consider adding the following to your `.bashrc`

```
if [ -z "$TMUX" ]; then
    base_session='my_session'
    # Create a new session if it doesn't exist
    tmux has-session -t $base_session || tmux new-session -d -s $base_session
    # Are there any clients connected already?
    client_cnt=$(tmux list-clients | wc -l)
    if [ $client_cnt -ge 1 ]; then
        session_name=$base_session"-"$client_cnt
        tmux new-session -d -t $base_session -s $session_name
        tmux -2 attach-session -t $session_name \; set-option destroy-unattached
    else
        tmux -2 attach-session -t $base_session
    fi
fi
```

You can see my use of this in my ZSH resource file at [my github repo](https://github.com/sparticvs/shellsync/blob/master/files/.zshrc)

Answer (score 3):

Here is an alternative solution from [this blog](https://davidtranscend.com/blog/check-tmux-session-exists-script/). Works like a charm.

> ```bsh
> session="main"
>
> # Check if the session exists, discarding output
> # We can check $? for the exit status (zero for success, non-zero for failure)
> tmux has-session -t $session 2>/dev/null
>
> if [ $? != 0 ]; then
>   # Set up your session
> fi
>
> # Attach to created session
> tmux attach-session -t $session
> ```

From [man page](http://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-current/man1/tmux.1#has-session)

> ```
> has-session [-t target-session] (alias: has)
> Report an error and exit with 1 if the specified session does not exist.
> If it does exist, exit with 0.
> ```

Answer (score 3):

Use this:

```
$ tmux a || tmux
```

The || operator is the opposite of the && operator, meaning the second command is performed if the first one *fails*.

Make an aliast of it if it's too long.

Comment: this is what I needed for connecting to Centos 7. [omitting the alternate gave me an exit]

Answer (score 2):

Drew Frank answered this here: https://superuser.com/questions/487363/tmux-equivalent-of-screen-r

Here's the script I now use for this (though, I've switched back to screen due to another issue with tmux) `/somewhere/on/your/path/ttmux` or as a shell function:

```
#!/bin/sh
# many thanks to Drew Frank: https://superuser.com/questions/487363/tmux-equivalent-of-screen-r
(tmux ls | grep -vq attached && tmux -2 at) || tmux -2
```

The `-2` options make tmux assume 256 color terminal support, so those may not be appropriate for your situation.

Answer (score 2):

I improved on @SuperMagic answer a little. I put this block at the top of my `.zshrc`

```
if [[ $TMUX = "" ]]; then
  # try to reattach sessions
  tmux ls | grep -vq attached && TMUXARG="attach-session -d"
  exec eval "tmux -2 $TMUXARG"
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

I did create this function, hope it helps!

```
tm() {
  local targetSession="$1"
  local DEFAULT_SESSION="main"

  [ -z "$targetSession" ] && targetSession="$DEFAULT_SESSION"

  tmux attach-session -t "$targetSession">/dev/null 2>&1 || \
    tmux new -s "$targetSession">/dev/null 2>&1
}

# If any, complete with a list of current tmux sessions
complete -C "tmux ls 2>&1 | cut -d':' -s -f1" tm
```

### EDIT:

```bash
_tm.getCurrenSession() tmux display-message -p '#S'

tm() {
  local targetSession=${1:='main'}

  # if outside tmux
  [[ -z "$TMUX" ]] && tmux new -A -s ${targetSession} && return $?

  if [[ "`_tm.getCurrenSession`" = "$targetSession" ]]
    then print "You did not move."; return 1
  fi

  # Create session if it doesn't exists
  tmux new -d -s ${targetSession} 2>/dev/null

  tmux switch-client -t ${targetSession}
}

_tm() {
  (( $CURRENT > 2 )) && return 0

  local tmuxList=( `tmux ls -F "#{session_name}"` )

  # if outside tmux
  [[ -z "$TMUX" ]] &&  _describe 'command' tmuxList && return 0

  local currentSession=( `_tm.getCurrenSession` )
  local actualList=(${tmuxList:|currentSession})
  _describe 'command' actualList
}

compdef _tm tm
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a zsh script [Eden Berger](https://edenberger.io/) and I wrote to do this.

If any unused (no clients attached) tmux sessions exist, then tmux will attach to one of them (the first, sorted by their session id).
Otherwise, a new tmux session will start.

It also supports skipping tmux altogether if already in a tmux session or if `SKIP_TMUX` is set.
I find the latter useful because this snippet is at the top of my `.zshrc`.
So, to run my terminal without starting or attaching a tmux session, I can run an occasional `SKIP_TMUX=1 alacritty`.

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env zsh

if [ -z $TMUX ] && [ -z $SKIP_TMUX ]; then
  delimiter=","
  sessions=$(tmux list-sessions -F "#{session_attached}${delimiter}#{session_id}")
  unused_sessions=$(echo $sessions | grep ^0)
  unused_sessions_ids=$(echo $unused_sessions | cut --delimiter=$delimiter --fields=2)
  sorted_unused_sessions_ids=$(echo $unused_sessions_ids | sort --numeric)
  first_unused_session_id=$(echo $sorted_unused_sessions_ids | head --lines 1)
  if [ -z $first_unused_session_id ]; then
    exec tmux new-session
  else
    exec tmux attach-session -t $first_unused_session_id
  fi
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

#### this help me to open `tmux` when `terminal` opened and attach `S1` if exist, if not exist: will be created

i have already a session called `S1`
for attach `tmux` to this `session` from `.zshrc` or `.bashrc` i'm add this in `.zshrc|.bashrc`

```
if [[ ! $TERM =~ screen ]]; then
    tmux attach -t tmux-ay || tmux new-session -s tmux-ay -n win1-ay
fi
```