# How can I start tmux automatically in fish shell while connecting to remote server via ssh

Tags: bash, ssh, tmux, fish, autologin

I switched from `bash` to `fish` shell. I liked it and decided to use it on my servers also. How can I start `tmux` automatically on `ssh` connection? I followed [this](http://william.shallum.net/random-notes/automatically-start-tmux-on-ssh-login) instruction for bash but `fish` shell is different and this recipe doesn't work without cardinal rewriting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Byobu](https://www.byobu.org/), a terminal multiplexer, based on tmux, offers an autostart feature.

Answer (score 5):

I rewrote script. The most tricky part was to disconnect from `ssh` by exiting from `fish` as `exit` inside `./.config/fish/config.fish` didn't work.

It starts `tmux` only if parent of the `fish` is `ssh`.

Here is part of my `./.config/fish/config.fish` file:

```
if status --is-login
    set PPID (echo (ps --pid %self -o ppid --no-headers) | xargs)
    if ps --pid $PPID | grep ssh
        tmux has-session -t remote; and tmux attach-session -t remote; or tmux new-session -s remote; and kill %self
        echo "tmux failed to start; using plain fish shell"
    end
end
```

More readable version can be found in my other question (thanks to [ridiculous-fish](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/29456/ridiculous-fish), author of fish shell): [How to use booleans in fish shell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/121807/how-to-use-booleans-in-fish-shell)

Answer (score 0):

Make a .fish file in `.config/fish/conf.d`:

```
if status --is-interactive
    echo server is interactive
    if set -q SSH_CONNECTION[1]; and set -q SSH_CLIENT[1]; and set -q SSH_TTY[1]; or pstree -p | grep "sshd.*\($fish_pid\)"; and not set -q TMUX
        tmux new -AD -t remote -s remote
    end
end
```

If your local machine also has a tmux session, then you have to use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> <kbd>D</kbd> to detach from remote session. More details [here](https://superuser.com/a/249671). To know why we are using `-AD` in the tmux command, please check [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/709471/206574).

**P.S.** Just to be clear about the accepted answer, normally fish is not set as the login shell. So, after ssh, we run `fish`. In that case `PPID` is `bash` and not `ssh`.