# How to use booleans in fish shell?

Tags: test, fish

I switched to `fish` shell and quite happy with it. I didn't get how can I handle booleans. I managed to write `config.fish` that executes `tmux` on `ssh` (see: [How can I start tmux automatically in fish shell while connecting to remote server via ssh](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/121401/how-can-i-start-tmux-automatically-in-fish-shell-while-connecting-to-remote-serv)) connection but I'm not happy with code readability and want to learn more about `fish` shell (I've already read tutorial and looked through reference). I want code to look like that (I know that syntax isn't correct, I just want to show the idea):

```
set PPID (ps --pid %self -o ppid --no-headers) 
if ps --pid $PPID | grep ssh 
    set attached (tmux has-session -t remote; and tmux attach-session -t remote) 
    if not attached 
        set created (tmux new-session -s remote; and kill %self) 
    end 
    if !\(test attached -o created\) 
        echo "tmux failed to start; using plain fish shell" 
    end 
end
```

I know that I can store `$status`es and compare them with `test` as integers but I think it's ugly and even more unreadable. So the problem is to reuse `$status`es and use them in `if` and `test`.

How can I achieve something like this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can structure this as an if/else chain. It's possible (though unwieldy) to use begin/end to put a compound statement as an if condition:

```
if begin ; tmux has-session -t remote; and tmux attach-session -t remote; end
    # We're attached!
else if begin; tmux new-session -s remote; and kill %self; end
    # We created a new session
else
    echo "tmux failed to start; using plain fish shell"
end
```

A nicer style is boolean modifiers. begin/end take the place of parenthesis:

```
begin
    tmux has-session -t remote
    and tmux attach-session -t remote
end
or begin
    tmux new-session -s remote
    and kill %self
end
or echo "tmux failed to start; using plain fish shell"
```

(The first begin/end is not strictly necessary, but improves clarity IMO.)

Factoring out functions is a third possibility:

```
function tmux_attach
    tmux has-session -t remote
    and tmux attach-session -t remote
end

function tmux_new_session
    tmux new-session -s remote
    and kill %self
end

tmux_attach
or tmux_new_session
or echo "tmux failed to start; using plain fish shell"
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried to find solution that is _exactly as in familiar languages_ and forgot about functions! I liked third variant the most because function names speak loud.