# Set default shell to tmux with options

Tags: tmux, raspbian

Following one of the comments of one of the responses to [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43601/how-can-i-set-my-default-shell-to-start-up-tmux) I've set my default shell to `/usr/bin/tmux`, which works perfectly fine.

But now I'd like if I could assign all logins to one account to be attached to the same window-group.
As per [this gist](https://gist.github.com/chakrit/5004006) that works by adding
`new-session -s main`
to ~/.tmux.conf and then invoking tmux as
`tmux new-session -t main`

Is there a way to have this be invoked as the login shell, or have tmux itself attach to the "main" window-group on launch by default?

Comment: I find it easier to run a normal shell and use `.bashrc` or `.zshrc` to create a new session or attach to an existing one - YMMV

Comment: And how do I do that?

Comment: Second answer in the question you linked.

Answer (score 0):

```
if command -v tmux &> /dev/null && [ -n "$PS1" ] && [[ ! "$TERM" =~ screen ]] && [[ ! "$TERM" =~ tmux ]] && [ -z "$TMUX" ]; then
   exec /usr/bin/tmux new-session -t main
fi
```

Added to the end of my `.bashrc` seems to do this as I wanted.