# How can I set my default shell to start up vim terminal?

Tags: linux, bash, vim

After causing an infinite recursion by putting

```
vim -c ':term ++curwin'
```

in my `~/.bashrc`, I wonder if there's a way to do it that actually works.

I know for tmux there's this solution:
[How can I set my default shell to start up tmux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43601/how-can-i-set-my-default-shell-to-start-up-tmux)

But in vim-terminal the `$TERM` variable stays the same.

Comment: Depending on your version, you could check the `VIM_TERMINAL` environment variable. See https://superuser.com/questions/1399061/how-to-differentiate-vim-terminal-from-regular-terminal-in-bash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable `VIM_TERMINAL` gets set when you are using the terminal inside `vim`. See the output of `env` inside `vim` terminal vs. outside.

So you can check for this being unset in your `.bashrc` and launch `vim` afterwards:

```
[ -z "$VIM_TERMINAL" ] && vim -c ":term ++curwin"
```

Comment: Is it possible to use conditionals in the vimrc based on this variable or does vim-terminal load the vimrc first and then sets this variable?
I want to create terminal-only settings in vimrc

Comment: I am not sure about that - but I'd say try it :) Or ask a new question if you get stuck